# With android studio no jvm found, JAVA_HOME has been set

Tags: java, android, installation, android-studio

I have a JAVA_HOME variable set to:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\
>   And the path to the jdk is:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

However when I try to start android studio I get the error:

> No JVM installation found. Please install a 64 bit JDK. If you already
>   have a JDK installed define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System
>   Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: Is this a system or a user environment variable.  That might make a difference? (Not sure)

Comment: It is an environment variable, have tried both, doesn't appear to make a difference

Comment: if you jdk is 64 bit it should be installed in "C:\Program Files\Java". "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java" is for 32 bits installs.

Comment: Can't I just use JDK 32 bits for my 64 bits PC?

Comment: For Windows 7 all Android Studio versions since 2022 don't work with symptoms like Java SDK, JAVA_HOME, etc  Don't waste the time - downgrade the version to Android Studio 4.0.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It says that it should be a 64-bit JDK. I have a feeling that you installed (at a previous time) a 32-bit version of Java. The path for all 32-bit applications in Windows 7 and Vista is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\
```

You were setting the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the 32-bit version of Java. Set your `JAVA_HOME` variable to the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
```

If that does not work, check that the JDK version is 1.7.0_45. If not, change the `JAVA_HOME` variable to (with `JAVAVERSION` as the Java version number:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdkJAVAVERSION
```

Comment: helpless for me

Answer (score 13):

Here is the tutorial :-
http://javatechig.com/android/installing-android-studio
and http://codearetoy.wordpress.com/2010/12/23/jdk-not-found-on-installing-android-sdk/

Adding a system variable JDK_HOME with value c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\ worked for me. The latest Java release can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
Additionally, make sure the variable JAVA_HOME is also set with the above location.

Please note that the above location is my java location. Please post your location in the path

Comment: I just had to add extra "\" at the end of jdk version. Before it was "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79" changed it to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\". How stupid that could be. :(

Answer (score 2):

Though, the question is asked long back, I see this same issue recently after installing Android Studio 2.1.0v, and JDK 7.80 on my PC Windows 10, 32 bit OS.  I got this error.

> No JVM installation found. Please install a 32 bit JDK. If you already
>   have a JDK installed define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System
>   Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

I tried different ways to fix this nothing worked. But As per System Requirements in this Android developer website [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

Its solved after installing JDK 8(jdk-8u101-windows-i586.exe) [JDK download site link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: I was running JDK-12.0.1 and nothing I did worked until I downloaded and installed the JDK8 but mine was a 64 bit version, and Android Studio worked thereon

Answer (score 2):

For me the case was completely different. I had created a **studio64.exe.vmoptions** file in **C:\Users\YourUserName\.AndroidStudio3.4\config**. In that folder, I had a typo of extra spaces. Due to that I was getting the same error.

I replaced the studio64.exe.vmoptions with the following code.

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

-server
-Xms1G
-Xmx8G
# I have 8GB RAM so it is 8G. Replace it with your RAM size.
-XX:MaxPermSize=1G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.1
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
```

Comment: yes, same happened with me, I just deleted vmoptions file and restarted studio...

Answer (score 1):

When you set to install it "for all users" (not for the current user only), you won't need to route Android Studio for the JAVA_HOME. 
Of course, have JDK installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the folder highlighted below. Depending on your Android Studio version, mine is 3.5 and reopen Android studio.

[image]