# Android Studio - No JVM Installation found

Tags: java, android, jvm, android-studio

I'm having issues trying to boot-up `Android Studio`

When I try to launch it after installation I'm getting this error:

`No JVM Installation found. Please install a 64 bit JDK.`

---

**My current system specification:**

Operating System: `Windows 8.0 64 bit version`
JDK installed: `JDK 1.8.0`

---

**What I have tried:**

I have tried what was reported in the error, and also in most of the solutions to set the `JDK_HOME` variable in environment variables to my JDK path (64 bit version) i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05`

*`*I also have tried rebooting system, just in case to test if the environment variable is not working without a restart`*

---

I have seen these solutions and tried but none of them works, so don't mark it as a duplicate of any of these:
[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found)
[With android studio no jvm found, JAVA_HOME has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033231/with-android-studio-no-jvm-found-java-home-has-been-set)
[Android Studio start fails on Windows 8 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596520/android-studio-start-fails-on-windows-8-64bit)
[Android Studio does not launch after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574544/android-studio-does-not-launch-after-installation)

---

Here is the cmd output for java version:

[image]

Comment: Just for reference, my JAVA_HOME is identical to yours, so you can rule that out as an issue as long as you're sure your JDK is 64-bit.

Comment: I installed x64 bit version of JDK .. also as you can see my JDK path its not inside `Program Files (x86)` folder so that clears this also ..

Comment: Just be on the safe side, please include the output of `java -version` in the question body.

Comment: I think you cant run Android Studio with Java 8. I installed Studio on a Mac Yosemite today and studio complained that it needed Java 6. Try installing java 7. On windows I used to have a Java 7 installed.

Comment: Well, that's my assumption too that it doesn't runs with java 8 .. but why and where it is reported ? as I can't see any where this thing listed ..

Comment: Read the system requirements at developer.android.com

Comment: make sure java bin path also set in "system variables".

Comment: For those getting this error on Windows 10, try installing JDK 7 64-bit from here - it worked for me. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: I have [answered on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532284/5376073) what was working for me.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried setting all kind of paths but nothing worked. So I had to do some dirty fix. The only problem with this is that it opens a blank command line window.

I did the following to make it work.

- goto the AndroidStudio installation folder.
- goto `bin` folder and open `studio.bat` in text editor
- add `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java2\jdk1.8.0`//your java path after the ECHO line.
- goto `Start` -> `All Programmes` -> `Android Studio` ->
- right click on `Android Studio` and click on `properties`.
- You will see the `Target` something like `<installation path>android-studio\bin\studio64.exe`
- change it to `<installation path>android-studio\bin\studio.bat`

Now you can access it by clicking it from the menu.

**Note :** I tried it with 8, It works.

Comment: This looks promising .. will give it a go .. will accept the answer if it works

Comment: No studio.bat in bin folder of Android Studio RC 1

Comment: That's correct, you have to create your own file named "studio.bat".

Comment: FYI: I was getting the same error but in my case I was pointing it to the bin folder in my Java_Home path.  Once I changed it to its parent folder to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25, everything went smooth.

Comment: @Hudixt It could be because you don't have permission to do so. Login as Admin and try.

Comment: In addition to Alexander, here is the content needed by "studio.bat" : @echo off #NEXT_LINE# set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31 #NEXT_LINE# cd "C:\Utilitaires\Development\Android Studio\bin" & Start studio64.exe (#NEXT_LINE# is here only for formatting)

Comment: I came across this issue today. When I installed android studio and jdk one day back everything worked fine. I went home and came back today and restarted the system, i got this error. I went through this thread, however, i just clicked on the android studio binary and right clicked and did run as administrator. The android studio came up fine. I am not sure but I think may be because i installed jdk as administrator I got this error while I was not running android studio as administrator. Last thing i am happy it worked for me. My installation jdk 1.8 64 bit , windows 8.1 64 bit.

Comment: I had this issue. The problem was that the start menu shortcut was launching `studio64.exe` whereas my `JAVA_HOME` was pointing at a 32 bit version. When I ran `studio.exe` instead, it started fine. I used this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55`

Comment: This answer seems to works for some of us. But on my other PC the funny this happened when I encountered this issue I just remove the JAVA_HOME just for curiosity then run the studio.exe well it works just try it might help you.

Answer (score 50):

I reproduced your issue on my **Windows 8.1** system :

1. Installed [64-bit JDK 1.8.0_11](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
2. Installed latest Android Studio Bundle.
3. Went to **Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...**
4. Added **JDK_HOME** pointing to my 64-bit JDK.
5. Launched **studio64.exe**

I got the same message you did. Thinking that it might be the environment variable, I did the following :

1. Went to **Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables...**
2. Changed the name of **JDK_HOME** to **JAVA_HOME**.
3. Launched **studio64.exe**

It came up successfully !

Comment: What does `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version` show for output?

Comment: just a crazy thought, maybe rename the JAVE_HOME variable a second time as JAVA_HOME, in case there is a space or non-printable character interfering?

Comment: This should be the selected ans

Answer (score 30):

1 .Download 64 bit version of JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

[image]

2. As shown in next picture, go to `Control Panel` -> `System and Security` -> `Advanced system settings` -> `Environment Variables` -> `New` (System variables)
3. Then add variable name: JAVA_HOME and variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25

Please note that `jdk1.8.0_25` may be vary depending on JDK version. 
[image]

4. Click OK button on the rest of the windows left.

Comment: I did all these steps but kept getting the error message, so I restarted the computer and now Android Studio launches.
I'm on Windows 10 Tech Preview.

Comment: Restarting the computer solves the problem when i completed all the above mentiond steps.

Comment: THAT DOES THE JOB!

Answer (score 11):

1-Right click on Android Studio and click on properties.

2-Replace studio64.exe in link by studio.exe.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to run on 64-bit. This one solves my problem. I realized that Android Studio has both version of EXE. So now I'm doing fine with latest JAVA SE 32 bit on 64 bit Windows 7. Thanks.

Comment: Replaced studio64.exe to studio.exe in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin folder and created a new shortcut of studio.exe on desktop. All doing great now. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, was having this issue as well and this is what fixed it for me. For the record I'm using Windows 8.1 and Java JDK 1.8.31, all 64-bit.

The problem is with the space between "Program" and "Files" in the path set in `JAVA_HOME`. I've had this problem before but didn't really realize until I was checking the instructions [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) for setting `JAVA HOME`, then it all made sense.

In a nutshell, change the `JAVA_HOME` path from:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`

to

`C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`

Make sure to set the correct JDK version number for your installation. Removing the space from the path fixed everything on my system.

As noted on the page linked above,

use `C:\Progra~1\` for `C:\Program Files\`

and `C:\Progra~2\` for `C:\Program Files(x86)\`

depending on where you have the JDK installed on your system.

Note: Just to be clear, before making this change my system correctly echoed the value of `JAVA_HOME` to be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` in the command window, leading me to believe all was well. However, attempting to run `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac` reported that the path could not be found. After removing the space from the `JAVA_HOME` path the same command runs perfectly.

Comment: In Windows 10 this solved my problem where setup would not work because it could not detect where the JDK was installed.  Stupid crap like this is why I hate Java.

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall Java 8 and clean your JDK_HOME and your JAVA_HOME enviromental paths. Then install 64bit JAVA 6 or 7 JDK of your preference.

Comment: I know I can make it work if I downgrade the JAVA version .. but why should I do so ? thats the question ..

Comment: As I'm trying to suggest, your JAVA enviromental paths are maybe dirty/duped from previous installations and confusing Android Studio. Intellij Idea is nearly JAVA 8 compatible, but you'll cannot exploit any JAVA 8 feature because Android doesn't support it yet. Just double check to clean it all and install JAVA 7, it will be fine.

Comment: Because you can't use Java 8 in Android.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set the path in the `SYSTEM VARIABLES` not in the `USER VARIABLES` also.....name the variable name as `JAVA_HOME` and the address as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\`    be sure that you didn't place any semicolon.

Comment: Your sample path helped me .. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle's [installation notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/install-windows-142126.html), you should download/install [JDK for the correct system](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u11-b12/jdk-8u11-windows-x64.exe). For your convenience, I have linked to it from the sentence above. If you still encounter problems, leave a comment. I have written some quick code that will tell you if [your JVM is 64 or 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062020/how-can-i-tell-if-im-running-in-64-bit-jvm-or-32-bit-jvm-from-within-a-program), below. I'd suggest you run this class and leave a comment as to its output:

```
public class CheckMemoryMode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have installed the same JDK .. JDK runs fine .. as I have no problems running programs over eclipse ..

Comment: Please compile/run the code I just added in and let me know what it says.

Comment: usually for all idea product there is a 'bat' launcher in bin directory. it clearly states that JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME both are accepted. Try to launch it and see what will happend after. At least if there is a problem u will see it in console. Then u can look into source of bat file. It is relly self describing.

Answer (score 1):

- For me this turns out to be Environment Variables not being inherited.
- Quick answer: reboot, than click on studio.bat, not studio.exe or studio64.exe

================ Details =================

- "Right Click"-"Run as Administrator" works for me **if**:
  **  JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME was set. (PATH didn't need to be changed for me)
  ** I run studio.bat, not studio.exe
  ** Note: By Default I am an administrator on a Microsoft Account (That Microsoft part may be affecting things), and I seldom reboot. I'm running Win8.1 64bit. I installed both JDKv1.8.0.0_25 32bit and 64 bit, and had JRE 32bit and 64 bit already installed (used by other software).
- I found there was a difference in clicking on studio.bat, studio.exe, and running studio.bat from a command prompt. There is also a difference if I rebooted or not.
- The difference: The System Environment Variables aren't all there depending on how I start the program.
- To test:
- In start menu drag a copy of "command prompt" to your desktop, then change properties so "Start In" is location of studio.bat
- copy studio.bat to studio_debug.bat (one we can mess with)
- drag a shortcut of studio_debug.bat to desktop for convenience.
- edit studio_debug.bat (right click --> edit)

== Change:

```
@echo off
```

== to

```
@echo on         
echo Set===================
set
echo ======================
pause
```

- This may also help in debugging studio.bat:

== change:

```
"%JAVA_EXE%" %ALL_JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" %MAIN_CLASS_NAME% %*
```

== to

```
echo =================
echo Starting: "%JAVA_EXE%" %ALL_JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" %MAIN_CLASS_NAME% %*
pause
"%JAVA_EXE%" %ALL_JVM_ARGS% -cp "%CLASS_PATH%" %MAIN_CLASS_NAME% %*
echo =================
```

- Now when you run studio.bat from command prompt versus double clicking you may see difference in environment variables including JAVA_HOME and PATH. If you do you have same problem as me.
- The problem seems to depend on:

  1. did you reboot since changing environment variables?
  2. didn't seem to matter if I was local or microsoft account
  3. may depend whether you are an administrator or other account type
  4. whether you start using studio.bat, studio.exe, or studio64.exe
- .
- FYI: The actual successful startup command executed by studio.bat on my system was as follows (includes studio64.exe):

  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe" "-Xms128m" "-Xmx750m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=350m" "-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m" "-ea" "-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false" "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" "-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false" "-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing" "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" "-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50" "-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" "-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio" "-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioBeta" -Djb.vmOptionsFile="C:\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions" "-Xbootclasspath/a:C:\android-studio\bin\../lib/boot.jar" -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudioBeta  -Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio  -cp "C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\extensions.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\util.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\jdom.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\log4j.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\android-studio\bin\..\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\lib\tools.jar" com.intellij.idea.Main
- Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that the installed version of both, Android Studio and JDK, are of either 32-bit or 64-bit. If JDK is of 32-bit and Android Studio of 64-bit or vice-verse, then it won't work though you set up JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to **remove** the double quotes that I had enclosed the JAVA_HOME path in.

Instead of declaring JAVA_HOME as "C\Program Files..."

I removed the " and declared JAVA_HOME as C\Program Files...

I am on Win 7, x64

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. The solution which helped me was I downloaded and installed 64 bit JDK from this [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and set the "**java_home**" variable to the new JDK installed path like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem after upgrading my machine from 7 to 10 had to reinstall the JDK all overgain and took me only a few seconds.
Here are the steps I followed.

Go to this link
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Agree to oracle contact agreement.Then pick your windows version in my case is 64 bit after that its ..Next..Next,,once compete you can relaunch your Android studio without any problem. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case

In `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables` there is no `JDK_HOME` OR `JAVA_HOME`

SO

**I added** an entry named: **JDK_HOME**   pointing to: **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\** (you have to point this to your JDK instalation path)

And all seems to work fine now

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio Works Perfectly fine with `Java 1.8` or `Java 8`. I was also having invalid JVM error. The reason was including ";" (semicolon) at the end of `JAVA_HOME` path value. The correct format for path value is:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx  (Replace xx with your current version)

Do not include `;` (semicolon) at the end of `JAVA_HOME` value

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solution.

Just start ANDROID STUDIO as **administrator** if you are using a non administrator windows profile!

If your environment variables are correct that will do the trick. Enjoy!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem. Try yourself

Answer (score 0):

You must just install jdk1.8.0 and then right click on my computer icon and then select properties,then in left panel, select advanced system settings, then in dialog bog select Environment Variables, then in that's dialog box,in section user variables create new variable that's name must be `JAVA_HOME` and path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0`(in my pc) then sytem variable section, select `PATH` variable and append it's end this path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin` and then select ok for all dialog box and after this steps run Android studio. And for test, run cmd in windows and run this command `java -version` if returned a java version and ... it is installed correctly.

Note: I get answer in windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested on my Windows 7 64Bit machine.

Quite strange... I had the same issue - WHILE IntelliJ Idea (including the Android Plug-in) was working perfectly.

However, here is what I did to get Android Studio 1.0 working (no step missing -> maybe it will help programming beginners).

Just set up a **new** environment variable by...

1. pressing Windows-Key and typing ***env***... you'll see "Edit the system environment variables". Click!
2. Now click "Environment Variables..."
3. Under **System variables** (NOT "User variables") add a new entry named `JAVA_HOME` and set the value to your Java folder (like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25`)
4. apply and you are good to go.

PS: I don't know why some people writing about nuclear science when they want to explain how to set the Java path..

Answer (score 0):

`My JAVA_HOME` was pointing to `c:/jre` directly. So I changed it to `C:/java/jre` because it was confused to pick up which one to use, so I changed it to the specific one and it works for me. Note: It is better to have only one JRE install on your machine

Answer (score 0):

The solution is given in the error itself, Goto My computer(Right click)-->properties-->Advanced system settings-->Environment variables-->Create new variable.

Give the following details to it:

Variable name : JAVA_HOME.

Variable value : (your path to java jdk installation folder).

To find the path for java installation, go to program files in your window installation drive (normally C drive). Find folder named JAVA, in that navigate to JDK folder.

Copy the link address from the top, and paste it in the Variable value .

Now Press Ok and once environment variable gets created restart the android studio.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if your "enviornment variables" set well, than try to update
 **Start > All Programs > Android Studio > Android Studio**

do right click, click **Properties** and set **android studio sdk** path

in

**shortcut > Target**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **windows 7**, make sure you install jdk-xxxx-windows-x64.exe.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
I had previously installed 32 bit instead of 64 bit version hence it was installed in program files x(86) folder. But if you install 64 bit sdk setup, its installed in program files folder.
Then set the JAVA_HOME='C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65'
It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My variables pointed to other system variables so JDK_HOME was

`%programfiles%\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`

and i had to explicitly change it to

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45`

Similar for JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in my case by deleting file

> **C:\Users\username.AndroidStudioX\studio64.exe.vmoptions**

***( x denotes the version of your android studio so it can be different )*** , because I created it before to customize VM options.
It's that simple

Answer (score 0):

Add the your installation path and java path to the default system path by separating the ;

Right click on My Computer-->Properties-->Advances System Setting-->Advanced -->Environment Variables-->Under System Variables category find the "Path"-->add the android installation path and java path by separating with ;...

Believe it works

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work after setting paths in environment variables correctly,
Reinstall Android Studio and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Under my Android Studio\bin there are two folder

studio.exe  and studio64.exe

I tried to run the first program and it gives me the mentioned error.

But when running  studio64.exe it works.

Answer (score 0):

If setting JAVA_HOME not works, install Visual Studio C++, you can download "all versions in one" installer here: https://www.techpowerup.com/download/visual-c-redistributable-runtime-package-all-in-one/

Answer (score -1):

I think Android does not support Java 8. Officially android need java 6 as mentioned at the below:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Here I'm providing you a good link, hope those will clear this question :

[Is it possible to use Java 8 for Android development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development)

Comment: No. Android supports JDK 7. You should check Android Studio instead of ADT. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Answer (score -1):

For crying out loud this is so VERY EASY TO Fix!!

1. Go to : "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System" once there click on "Advanced system settings" on the left hand side
2. The window that pops shows a box that says says `Environment Variables`! Click it.
3. Click "add new" to add new variable.
4. Type `JAVA_HOME` in the first box and in the second box the address to, IE / in my case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25` save it. exit everything. THATS IT!!

Enjoy Android Studio! 
Obviously for the above to work you have to install java first or how else can you use it or point to it on your pc and all that. The above instructions are amazingly mislead and complicated. For the record I am on widows 8.1, YES it works on latest windows and is ridiculously simple to fix.

-OSG

Comment: Just a suggestion, but try not talking down to people and I think you'll be better received. Many people, myself included, have done exactly what has been suggested - added the system env var `JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK folder location, checked that it is correct by echoing `%JAVA_HOME%` (set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`) in the cmd prompt and it appears to all be correctly set, but Android Studio fails to start, showing the "invalid JVM installation" message. With this much activity it's clearly not "ridiculously simple to fix" for everyone.

Comment: @randall: Most answers to this question are same like this one, but its sad that people do not even read the whole question before answering, in the question itself I have mentioned that I tried this.

Answer (score -1):

**Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables**

I changed **JAVA_HOME** to **JAVA** and again changed **JAVA** to **JAVA_HOME**.

and Its working fine.