# How to run Android Studio with specified JDK, but without changing JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm using some sort of Java apps that use `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but need that environment variable is set to 32-bit version of JDK. I'm using 64-bit Windows. When i start Android Studio i get error like below. I've set env variables like `ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK` and `JDK_HOME` pointing to jdk 64bit, but i see that `JAVA_HOME` has higher priority and error is the same. What can i do? In eclipse environment i can set this in `eclipse.ini`. Is something like that for new Android Studio (`build 135.1623071`) ?

> No JVM installation found. Please install a 64 bit JDK. If you already
>   have a JDK installed define a JAVA_HOME variable in Computer > System
>   Properties > System Settings > Environment Variables.

Comment: I had the same problem and did what this answer points.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found

Comment: Thank You. Voted as duplicate.

Comment: @marioosh, may i suggest that you should simply delete the question instead of voting/closing?