# Android studio not recognized jvm even if i already installed the jdk

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, jvm

First of all, I know that this question has been asked before maybe more than once, like this one for instance [Android Studio - No JVM Installation found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found) but i couldn't know the path that i have to refered to.

i already installed `jdk-8u31-windows-x64` and i am working on `windows 7 64 bit`, when i open Android Studio, i got message:

[image]

it seems obvious that i should add a `JAVA_HOME` system variable, but what is the value of that variable?

after installing `jdk-8u31-windows-x64`, i found this folder on my computer 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31`, should I refered to it? or to the bin inside it? or should I install other stuff?

#### Note 1:

when I type `java -version` on my cmd, I got this:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

#### Note 2:

Yesterday I formatted my laptop and installed the latest version of java from the official website of java

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31 is the jre folder, not the jdk folder.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti okay but why when i installed `jdk-8u31-windows-x64`, i got the jre folder?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti plus, i found that jdk on the official website of oracle, here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti do you suggest installing something else please? give me links please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JAVA_HOME` should contain the path of the 64-bit JDK.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_31` is the path of a JRE. Normally the JDK directory should be something like `jdk1.8.0_31` in your case, and the `JAVA_HOME` would store the absolute path of this directory, without the `bin` directory. Try searching for that directory under `C:/Program Files` (`C:/Program Files(x86)` is usually for 32-bit installations).

It would be better to also install JDKs in a path that does not have space.

Comment: i found this path in my machine `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`, should I refer to it please?

Comment: Yes that should be it.

Comment: with or without `/` at the end? like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31` or `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\ `  ?

Comment: I don't think it would matter but no need for the slash at the end.

Comment: I made that variable without the `\ ` and the android studio is trying to work, now, many thanks plus one