# Android Studio could not detect JDK7 or newer

Tags: java, android

I was trying to install the android studio in my computer (Win 10 - 64x). 
By the name, probably the version is 1.4.1: 
android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows.exe

But I keep receiving a error saying: "We could not detect a Java Development Kit (jdk) v7 or newer on your system."

Currently, I have the jdk1.8.0_71 (64x) version installed. The environment variables **JAVA_HOME** and **JDK_HOME** (not sure if this specific one is really necessary) set, and the Path has been edited as well.

[As you can see here, every variable and settings are set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iboIX.png)

Also, I've tried changing the jdk version to the 1.7.0_79 (64x), and I've also tried placing the path between quotes.. But all of it was in vain

It is strange, because I'm a java developer (not android), and I've never seen something like that.

p.s.: Every time I change the system environment variables I restart the computer to ensure the functionality of those variables.

Comment: whats the error msg u are getting?

Comment: have you gone through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found/27576779#27576779)

Comment: Have you set ANDROID_HOME  variable path ?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure both your **Android Studio** & **JDK 7** are of either of `64bit` or `32bit` both. If **JDK** is of `32bit` and **Android Studio** of `64bit` or vice verse, It won't work together.

Assumed that, you have set your `JAVA_HOME` & `PATH` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you SO MUCH Grimmy Vorner!!

I spent my day reading everything and I finally was able to get it working by using the "SDK tools package" (android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows.zip) instead of the "Android Studio package" (android-studio-bundle-143.2915827-windows.exe) from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Also, go to Build -> Edit Build Types -> SDK Location -> JDK Location and make sure it is pointing to the correct jdk version (JDK 7 or JDK 8).

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything that all of you said, but nothing seemed to work. After all I discovered that I can download a zipped version instead of an installation wizard. All I had to do was unzip the android studio and execute the studio64.exe file, and then everything worked perfect.

Still don't understand why it was not working properly with the installation wizard..

Anyway, thank you all for you effort!

I hope that all this information can help others in the future!