# The environment variable does not point to valid JVM installation

Tags: android

I installed JDK and gave its path but after giving the path I am getting JVM installation problem. I even tried to give path upto jdk1.7 instead of bin but idea did not work. please help.[

Comment: Could you open cmd and type java -version  ? You should get you java version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - No JVM Installation found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found)