# Intellij no JVM installation found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When starting Intellij I am getting the following error:

> No JVM Installation found. Please install a 64-bit JDK.

However, I have already downloaded and configured the JDK.

So my `JAVA_HOME` in System Variables is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4` and `PATH` is set to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If type `"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" -version` at the command prompt, does it work?

Comment: Yes, returns the version of Java installed

Comment: This *looks* like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898684/android-studio-no-jvm-installation-found but it looks like you've already done the things offered as solutions to that question, and you still have the problem.

Comment: What version of IntelliJ do you have? If it's an old version it might not have support for Java 9

Answer (score 0):

[Intellij link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

This link goes intellij kindly referr this site