# Android Studio - JAVA_HOME doesn't point to a valid JVM installation

Tags: java, android, jvm

Having trouble firing up android studio. Get the following message: The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of ?C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31) does not point to a valid JVM installation. The problem is that as far as I can tell, the environment variable I set up IS pointing to a valid install.

I've tried everything from renaming it to JDK_HOME, to pointing it to all the sub directories in the jdk folder, to uninstalling and reinstalling java and android studio about 3 time. I have triple checked that I have 64 bit JAVA installed (and that my computer is 64 bit). Pretty much at the end of my rope here. Help would be appreciated big time.

Here's a screen cap of my windows, you might spot something obvious I haven't:

[image: a screen cap of my windows]

Comment: Look into the link below you have to change your jdk location in studio


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20033812/4384828

Comment: if you go to `File -> Other Setttings -> Default Project Structure` ... what do you see on JDK installation?

Comment: You have %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the "Path" variable?? Have you tryed with java 7??

Comment: @Sanjay I've looked through that thread a couple of times now and I don't know what you're referring to. The jdk is in the right place because it's 64 bit. When you say I have to change it in Studio do you mean I have to edit Android Studio files?

Comment: have you tried user3232025 answer?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Are you talking about Adnroid Studio? I can't launch it in the first place, I just get a window with the error message above.

Comment: @Sanjay This is weird... I can only see three answers, one from hichris123, one from Rahul Gupta and one from ejmin. Can't even find a user3232025 in any of the comments. Could you copy/paste what they said?   EDIT: Just noticed he posted in this thread, whoops! Will try it now.

Answer (score 29):

You can try this
[Android Studio error: "Environment variable does not point to a valid JVM instalation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185358/android-studio-error-environment-variable-does-not-point-to-a-valid-jvm-instal/25622913#25622913)

this works for me.
If you start 64bit Android Studio, you have to add JAVA_HOME as

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk..."
```

If 32bit

```
"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk..."
```

and dont put "\bin" end of the path.

Comment: Make sure you don't actually type the quotation marks. Once I removed those, mine worked fine (win7x64).

Answer (score 13):

As you told you have 64 bit system then copy this path **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31**

**Step 1 :-**  Create  **JAVA_HOME**  variable by clicking new  and past    ( C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31) this  path.

**Step 2** Then click path variable and edit then past it your path after add **semicolon (;)** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

[image]

I am using **windows 10** so this windows look like this

[image]

**Note :-** If above dialog not open then 
, select path variable and click on Edit…. Locate the end of the current variable value
**append the path of jdk, using a semicolon** And click ok

Comment: your wc happy to hear that

Comment: Thanks bro, I was adding semicolon in place of backslash as a value of JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 8):

To fix it, just remove "\bin" from my JAVA_HOME variable.

**NOTE:** be sure to put the **`JAVA_HOME`** path variable in the **`System variables`** rather than the **`user variables`**. If the path variable is in User the Android Studio will not find the path.

Answer (score 6):

If you are sure that the variable is pointing to the right place, then:

Acess "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin"

Choice the .exe for your machine.

[image]

Comment: You are correct, wasted 30 minutes searching why it not working and it worked when tryied studio64.exe.
- thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Faced same problem for many weeks.
What worked for me:
uninstalled all java from laptop
then installed jdk 7 64 bit,
deleted JAVA_HOME and added JDK_HOME.

Answer (score 4):

To fix **Android Studio - JAVA_HOME doesn't point to a valid JVM installation Problem**,  follow the below steps:

**Step 1:** Open the command window by typing ‘**cmd**‘ in the Start menu search box.

**Step 2**: Now change the directory to the Android studio installation :

> cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin"

**Step 3:** Type ‘**studio.bat**‘ and hit enter. If the JAVA environment variables are not set properly, then you should get an error message as below.

[image]

**Step 4:** So, it is clear that Android studio is not able to read the JDK location. All you need to do is, set the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME [environment variables by following the steps mentioned in this guide.](https://techglimpse.com/windows-add-new-modify-operating-system-variables/)

[image]
[image]

**Step 5:** Close the existing command window. This step is very important, as the newly set variable will not reflect otherwise.

**Step 6:** Re-launch the command window and type the below command to ensure that the environment variables are set properly.

> echo %JAVA_HOME%
>
> echo %JDK_HOME%
>   [image]

**Step 7:**  Now change the directory to the Android studio installation.

> cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\bin"

**Step 8:** Type **‘studio.bat‘** and hit enter. Now the Android studio will launch normally.

Based on these link : [Google Android Studio is not launching?](https://techglimpse.com/google-android-studio-launching-fix-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

I use Windows 8.

2 steps:

1. Download `jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe`

   1.1 It's a requirement @ https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Requirements
2. Set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80`

***NOTE***: not in `Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you have to set the JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31, just like you set the variable JDK_HOME. :)

See this post for reference:
[Android Studio installation on Windows 7 fails, no JDK found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574189/android-studio-installation-on-windows-7-fails-no-jdk-found?rq=1)

Also, you could try installing an older version of java, as the newest ones might not be compatible with your IDE. Reference: [Android Studio error: "Environment variable does not point to a valid JVM installation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185358/android-studio-jdk-error-solved-closed?rq=1)

Comment: I have both variables set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Comment: Maybe try installing an older version of java. The brand new ones are not always compatible with the developer environment.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure `JAVA_HOME` is in the "System Variables" and points to the JDK short path. For example if the JDK is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79` set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_7` .
I was getting the above error message initially upon install but it started working when I made this change, and it was not necessary to reboot.

Answer (score 2):

make `JAVA_HOME` a system variable under environment variables and set it to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31`.

**After that logout and login back**. This should eliminate the error message that you are getting. Then launch the Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

> JAVA_HOME path : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\                  //Copied from PATH variable.

Remove quotes if any.

If your system is 32 bit then execute studio.exe

If your system is 64 bit then simply execute studio64.exe

It solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing all the versions of JDK and changing the user environment variable. Only the following worked. Install the same versions and you are good to go.

1. Android studio version is 2.1.2
2. Install Java jdk1.8.0_91
3. Add the following user environment variable JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in your system Variable ( path ) append this wilset the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Comment: I think you are trying to say that the correct path(e.g. `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`) containing the Java executable (e.g. `java.exe`) should be in the PATH environment variable as well, but the answer is quite unreadable right now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you just have to do the following:

```
 `Go to Control Panel> Advanced System Settings> Environment Variables
 > System Variables> New> Variable name: JDK_HOME
                          Variable value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\

 and then click on android studio..It will start working.`
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using windows 7 32-bit and this worked for me:

Added new system variable: **JDK_HOME** with correct location of my JDK:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151

Answer (score 1):

For this issue, I download the jdk oracle version 11 on the official java website, I then set the JAVA_HOME in the environment variable to the jdk path for both the user and system. It is important that it is jdk and not type jre. Hopefully this helps. Run the Android studio 64-bit type, if does not work try the 32-bit.

I found there is some issue if you download the wrong version of 32 or 64 bit version so be careful on that.

Answer (score 0):

For me it got fixed when I removed the leading and trailing double quotes in the JAVA_HOME system environment variable (Windows 7 x64):

Did ***NOT*** work: `"C:\path\to\jdk\without\bin"`
Did work: `C:\path\to\jdk\without\bin`

Note:
I do not have any spaces in the path to the JDK (custom location)!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Download your version of jdk exe file and run it. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
Step 2) Once installation is complete, you will see the jdk directory in Java folder in Program files under C Drive
Step 3) Right click on my computer, then click on advance settings, then click on environment settings. 
Step 4) add a new variable called JAVA_HOME and set its path to PATH = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\
Step 5) Run Android Studio :)

Answer (score 0):

FOR JAVA RELATED INSTALLATION THIS IS THE PATH SETTING ARE MATCHED N RUNS YOUR INSTALLATIONS SUCCESSFUL.

Step 1 :- Create JAVA_HOME variable by clicking new and past ( C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31) this path.

Step 2 Then click path variable and edit then past it your path after add semicolon (;) C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

Answer (score 0):

MY COMPUTER
|
RIGHT CLICK
|
PROPERTIES
|
ADVANCED SYSTEM SETTINGS
|
ADVANCED TAB
|
ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
|
USER VARIABLES
|
NEW
|
VARIABLE NAME = JAVA_HOME
VARIABLE VALUE = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"

REMOVE BIN, IF YOU ADDED ALREADY...

Hi! It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

We can also resolve this issue by using jdk 8 
to install jdk 8 click here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.htmli
and download jdk setup install it 
to copy the path go to c drive select programme file folder then choose java
then choose jdk and you will  see the version go to that folder and copy the path and right click on my computer go to properties then choose advance settings then you will see one pop pup in that you have to choose  variables.and click on new tab and give the name of variable JAVA_HOME and in the path you need to past the path that you have copy for jdk 8
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ifax.png)

after that you have to click ok ok two times
now start your android studio error will be resolved

Answer (score -1):

Delete your all user variable paths from Environments Variable, and keep only two (TEMP & TMP) variables, it will work.