# android programming using Go mobile error import go.hello.Hello

Tags: android, mobile, go

I have question about error while importing import.hello.Hello in android studio, as you see in the picture below. please give me solution how to solve this error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See here [@Arpit Patel answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345340/android-studio-java-home-doesnt-point-to-a-valid-jvm-installation/36708374#36708374) You need to set the path like that

As you told you have 64 bit system then copy this path **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31**

**Step 1 :-**  Create  **JAVA_HOME**  variable by clicking new  and past    ( C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31) this  path.

**Step 2** Then click path variable and edit then past it your path after add **semicolon (;)** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

[image]

I am using **windows 10** so this windows look like this

[image]

**Note :-** If above dialog not open then 
, select path variable and click on Edit…. Locate the end of the current variable value
**append the path of jdk, using a semicolon** And click ok