# Download Android Studio ide Only

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

There is a chance my question is related to other questions.but i want to download Android studio ide only. Because I already have Android studio. I have an error with running Android studio like. JAVA_HOME DOESN'T HAVE VALID JVM INSTALLATION SO I want Try uninstall and reinstall Android Studio. I Uninstalled but I don't have Android Studio installer because I copyed Android Studio from another laptop. My another laptop is dead. I don't want to waste my 900 mb internet. Please help me.

Comment: try looking at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345340/android-studio-java-home-doesnt-point-to-a-valid-jvm-installation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - JAVA\_HOME doesn't point to a valid JVM installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345340/android-studio-java-home-doesnt-point-to-a-valid-jvm-installation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set JAVA_HOME variable to run Android Studio .
Steps to set *JAVA_HOME* variable:

1. locate your java installation directory.
2. Open Command Prompt (make sure you Run as administrator so you're able to add a system environment variable).
3. make sure to replace [JDK PATH] with your java installation directory.

> *setx -m JAVA_HOME "[JDK PATH]"*

4. restart Android Studio